# randomly assign teachers to a school with dplyr or similar?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame with 8 schools and its characteristics, and another with 48 teachers and its characteristics. I can generate some fake data with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
set.seed(6232015)
n.schools <-8
n.teachers <- 48

  makeRandomString <- function(pre, n=1, length=12) {
  randomString <- c(1:n)                  # initialize vector
  for (i in 1:n) {
    randomString[i] <- paste0(pre,'.', paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                                    length, replace=TRUE),
                                             collapse="")) 
  }
  return(randomString)
}

gen.teachers <- function(n.teachers){
  Teacher.ID <- makeRandomString(pre= 'T', n = n.teachers, length = 20)
  Teacher.exp <- runif(n = n.teachers, min = 1, max = 30)
  Teacher.Other <- sample(c(0,1), replace = T, prob = c(0.5, 0.5), size = n.teachers)
  Teachers <- data.frame(Teacher.ID, Teacher.exp, Teacher.Other)
  return(Teachers)
}



gen.schools <- function(n.schools){
  School.ID <- makeRandomString(pre= 'S', n = n.schools, length = 20)
  School.lat <- runif(n = n.schools, min = -2, max = 2)
  School.long <- runif(n = n.schools, min = -2, max = 2)
  Schools <- data.frame(School.ID, School.lat, School.long) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%  mutate (School.distance = distHaversine(p1 = c(School.long, School.lat),
                                                           p2 = c(0, 0), r = 3961))
  return(Schools)
}

Teachers <- gen.teachers(n.teachers = n.teachers)
Schools <- gen.schools(n.schools = n.schools)
```

To each shool, I want to assign 6 teachers (every teacher get 1 and only 1 school). I could use:

```
Teachers %>% sample_n(6)
```

To get a list of 6 teachers assign those to a school, remove them from my original pool and keep going with a loop. My guess/hope is that there is a much easier way of doing this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're getting an error, note a typo in the word "length" repeated several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of your code

```
sample(rep(Schools$School.ID, each = 6))
```

gives a random sequence of schools where each school.id appears 6 times.  Set Teachers$AssignedSchool to this sample and each teacher has an assigned school

Comment: `split(Teachers, sample(rep(Schools$School.ID, each = 6)))`